# split webpage for text and img help CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

iv been working on a webpage and so far its getting to my liking. im trying to get my text and an img in my main content to split down the center having the img on the right and the text on the left hand side. i have that!! however im trying to push the img to the right and the text to the right just a tad to get it off the left hand side of the page. as of right now they both sit on the left hand side of the page but they are split as desired. iv tried setting my margin on my img to the right but then i cant move the text (padding as well). ive tried my .main{} having the align-content: center; and that does nothing. i cant seem to figure it out i will have a photo of the webpage as is and my code down below. any help will be much appreciated im still relatively new to programming.  [image: content of page]

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-content {
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
}

.top-content img {
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-bar li {
    float: left;
}

.nav-bar a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.author {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(50%);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.photo img {
    height: 97%;
    width: 70%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
    
}

main {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;     
}

.main-content {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 400px);
}

.main-content h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/practice3.css">
        <title>practice3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="top-content">
                <ul class="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="./imgs/helping.jpg" alt="photo">
                <div class="author">
                <h1>ARC Ulster green</h1>
                <h3>Always there, Always Caring</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="main-content">
                <h1>We Strive to touch hearts</h1>
                <h3 class="two">Each and every day</h3>
                <p>Since the begining our support staff have shown
                a dedication to helping people and bettering their lifes.
                and as a consiquence our individuals feel more confident 
                and happy than ever. As we continue our mission to help those
                who need it we have seen our individuals prosper to become
                independent living in the community among the rest of the                     world.
                we are proud to serve our community not only because we care,                 but also 
                because we want to see our individuals live long happy lives
                with joy and laughter while they learn valuable skills in the                 proccess.
                everyday our staff walks into their job site ready, willing,                   and
                confident that they will complete their mission to provide
                the best care around and that is an ARC gaurentee. as we                       always 
                strive to beat expectations and go above and beyond for those                 in our care.
                 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="photo">
                <img src="./imgs/staff.jpg" alt="staff">
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out i added margin-left: to the .main{} and now im adjusting the photo margins.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should really look into flexbox initially and CSS Grid. For positioning. Even though you solved it, in the future this will help you a ton.
Here are my favorite resources for them.
Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

CSS Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Some simple practice with flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

These are a game changer when you are starting out. Good luck on the journey.